# ¿Como puedo ocupar un modelo varias veces en asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Lo que pasa es que creo un modelo de cada tabla de mi base de datos sql server y un contexto de todas las tablas con Scaffold-DbContext "mi cadena" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context TrabajoContext,
Después ocupo solo utilizo el modelo de la tabla Usuario, con ese creo un login y todo va bien, creo una sesión con HttpContext.Session.SetString, al entrar con el login, pero en mi modelo solo utilizo el Required en los dos campos que utilizo para el login, que son la contraseña y el correo, cuando entro y hago un formulario para registrar más usuarios, al momento de poner a todos los campos el Required, el login deja de funcionar, debido a que requiere los otros campos del modelo. Mi pregunta es como puedo ocupar el mismo modelo para que solo ocupe estos dos campos en el login y después entrando en la sesión pueda ocupar todos los campos para insertar más usuarios.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TRABAJO.Models
{
    public partial class Usuario
    {
        public Usuario()
        {
            Agenda = new HashSet<Agenda>();
        }
        //si pongo un [Required] en cualquiera que no sea correo o contraseña mi login deja de servir
        public string Curp { get; set; }
        public string Matricula { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string ApPat { get; set; }
        public string ApMat { get; set; }
        public string Direcciom { get; set; }
        public string NumExterior { get; set; }
        public string NumInterior { get; set; }
        public int CodigoPostal { get; set; }
        public string Colonia { get; set; }
        public string Demarcacion { get; set; }
        public string EntidadFederativa { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere de la contraseña")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Contrasena { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedUs { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere el usuario")]
        public string Correo { get; set; }
        public int IdTipoTrabajor { get; set; }

        public TipoTrabajor IdTipoTrabajorNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controlador

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Usuario user)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var account = _context.Usuario.Where(u => u.Correo == user.Correo && u.Contrasena == user.Contrasena).FirstOrDefault();
                if(account != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Curp", account.Curp.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nombre", account.Nombre.ToString());
                    return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos.");
                }
            }
            return View();


        }
public ActionResult RegisterU(Usuario user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Usuario.Add(user);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = user.Nombre + " " + user.ApPat + " " + "registrado con exito.";
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Vista

```
@model TRABAJO.Models.Usuario
@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Correo" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Correo" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Correo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Contrasena" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Contrasena" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Contrasena" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Iniciar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Soy novata en esto de asp.net core, solo había usado mvc en php y apenas comienzo a usar .net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes añadir una clase solo para el inicio de sesión de hecho podrás ver que al crear un nuevo proyecto te da la opción de crearlo con cuentas de autenticacion individuales y ah  usa la clase de la tabla   para registrar los usuarios y una clase para el inicio de sesión algo así quedaría:

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Correo")]

        public string Correo{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Contrasena{ get; set; }

    }
```

Vista

en la linea donde haces uso del modelo usuario  lo cambias por LoginViewModel

> @model TRABAJO.Models.LoginViewModel

```html
@model TRABAJO.Models.LoginViewModel
@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Correo" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Correo" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Correo" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Contrasena" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Contrasena" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Contrasena" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Iniciar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controlador

cambiamos el modelo recibido que tu tienes  `usuario`  por el que creamos  `InicioSesion`  asi es como lo comparas dentro del controlador

> public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel InicioSesion)

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel InicioSesion)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            var account = _context.Usuario.Where(u => u.Correo == InicioSesion.Correo && u.Contrasena == InicioSesion.Contrasena).FirstOrDefault();
                if(account != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Curp", account.Curp.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Nombre", account.Nombre.ToString());
                    return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos.");
                }
            }
            return View();


        }
```

la clase puedes agregarla en la carpeta de modelos

Comment: pero, esa clase la tengo que agregar en mi contexto, o como la utilizaría para hacer referencia con mi base de datos?

Comment: Esta bien la idea, pero deberías adecuar tu respuesta al código avanzado que tiene la OP. Está demás el uso del método asíncrono incluso.

Comment: editando........

Comment: espero se entienda mejor

Comment: Una duda, lo que yo entendia, era que los clases (modelos) que solo tiene el contexto, son los que pueden acceder a la base de datos, entonces puedo crear modelos aparte que no se hayan creado  con el  Scaffold-DbContext ? y como puedo utilizar estos para recuperar los datos y comparar e insertar con la base? Disculpa, pero no he entendido bien este framework, llevo una semana trabajando con el.

Comment: Realmente no son los modelos los que acceden a la base de datos, simplemente representan un registro y la estructura de alguna tabla. Para manipular la base de datos se utiliza el `context` que a su vez utiliza los modelos para devolver la información con el "formato" de tu modelo.
Si te das cuenta, en el código no se utiliza el `ViewModel` para buscar en la base de datos, si no que se llama a la tabla `Usuario` (del context) y se busca dentro de ella, un registro que tenga el mismo contenido que el del `LoginViewModel`.

Comment: Vendría siendo
`_context.Usuario.Where(usuario => usuario.Correo == InicioSesion.Correo && usuario.Contrasena == InicioSesion.Contrasena).FirstOrDefault();`
Si no tienes problemas con el inglés, [aquí](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/model-and-viewmodel-in-asp-net-core/) puedes ver las diferencias entre los modelos y las vistas-modelo; y [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/querying/) para ver cómo accede a la base de datos el Entity Framework. 
Si no te convence, siempre puedes hacer una nueva pregunta específica acerca del tema :)

Comment: En este caso usarias dos tipos de modelos, uno para guaradar en BD tal y como tu entendias, los que estan en el contexto y otro para crear un formulario de login con los datos que solo quieres recoger en ese momento que seria LoginViewModel tal y como dice Xique